# Have CMake execute a file which is not CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

Is that true that you can't customize the name of your `CMakeLists.txt` file? I read in a few places that `make` suffers from the same problem, but that's completely not true, you sure can:

```
~$ make -f whatever_name_you_feel_like
```

Can't you do this with CMake?

My situation is as follows: The project leader wants to have a certain CMakeLists.txt file run in the CI workflow and another when developing. I thought it would be possible to just keep 2 CMake files and tell `cmake` which one to execute.

Comment: You cannot customize a name of the `CMakeLists.txt` file which is processed by CMake when it builds the project. For achieve different behavior between development and CI builds you could make your `CMakeLists.txt` to be dependent on some option(s), and pass the additional option during CI configuration (or during development configuration).

Comment: USE CASE:  In a testing framework input files from a clients project are used to generate many mini-projects. The `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` for all _should_ be the `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` where the tests where defined; but each instance is given its own `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. Obviously the desired `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` will contain a `CMakeLists.txt` we _don't own_, and we mustn't change files there. So we can drive the same parameterized `CMakeLists.txt` for all test cases, but it can't be in the desired `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use file with a name different to `CMakeLists.txt`, but I'm almost certain that's not actually what you want to do anyways.

I assume the cl version and the development version are mostly similar and only some details change. In this case you should not duplicate the logic. Instead add one or multiple options to your cmake project that can set when you set up the build dir and can even be changed without reconfiguring the whole project from scratch. Basically you add a cache variable to `CMakeLists.txt` which allows the user to overwrite the default value via `-D` command line option. The value can also be modified after the initial configuration using `cmake-gui`.

```
cmake_mimimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)

project(MyProject)

# option set to true by default
set(MY_PROJECT_COMMAND_LINE_BUILD 1 CACHE BOOL "Use the command line configuration for MyProject")

#logic common to both configurations
add_executable(MyProg foo.cpp bar.cpp)

if(MY_PROJECT_COMMAND_LINE_BUILD)
    #logic only for command line build
    target_compile_definitions(MyProg PRIVATE COMMAND_LINE_BUILD)
else()
    # logic only for non-command line build
    target_compile_definitions(MyProg PRIVATE DEVELOPMENT_BUILD)
endif()
```

Ironically you could set up both from the command line:

- Command line build

  ```
  cmake -S sourceDir -B buildDir
  ```
- Development build

  ```
  cmake -D MY_PROJECT_COMMAND_LINE_BUILD:BOOL=0 -S sourceDir -B buildDir
  ```

If you don't want to enter the cache values in the command line every time you set up the project, you could also use a cmake script file to initialize the cache values using the `-C` command line option.

```
cmake -C developmentVersion.cmake -S sourceDir -B buildDir
```

developmentVersion.cmake:

```
set(MY_PROJECT_COMMAND_LINE_BUILD 0 CACHE BOOL "Use the command line configuration for MyProject")
```

---

*Theoretically you could the whole `CMakeLists.txt` file in an `if` `else` `endif` structure and use `include` in one of the alternatives to competely replace the standard logic in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but imho this is not a good idea.*

Answer (score 1):

> Can't you do this with CMake?

No, it's not possible.

> The project leader wants to have a certain CMakeLists.txt file run in the CI workflow and another when developing.

One way: copy or symlink proper `CMakeLists.txt` before executing `cmake`.

Preferably one would use cmake scripting language:

```
   #  CMakeLists.txt
   if (MODE STREUQAL "CI_WORKFLOW")
       include(CMakeLists-ci-workflow.txt)
   elseif (MODE STREQUAL "DEVELOPING")
       include(CMakeLists-developing.txt)
   else()
       message("SUPER ERROR")
   fi()
```

and then separate `CMakeLists-ci-workflow.txt` and separate `CMakeLists-developing.txt` and do `cmake -D MODE=DEVELOPING` or `-D MODE=CI_WORKFLOW`.

But overall, the idea of "separate CMakeLists.txt" sounds bad to me. Instead use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` for developing and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` for release builds, and use other cmake variables to differentiate settings, instead of duplicating configuration.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `cmake -E` rather than `cmake -D`? If so, please explain

Comment: No I'm not, sure I mean -D`.